# Move Files with Python from One Json File into Another with Different Structure

Tags: python, json

**Can anyone help me solve this,**
**I am kinda trying for some days.

*I have this kind of JSON File***

```
[
    {
      "city": "Bucharest", 
      "lat": "44.4000", 
      "lng": "26.0833", 
      "country": "Romania", 
      "iso2": "RO", 
      "admin_name": "Bucureşti", 
      "capital": "primary", 
      "population": "1883425", 
      "population_proper": "1883425"
    }, 
    {
      "city": "Timişoara", 
      "lat": "45.7597", 
      "lng": "21.2300", 
      "country": "Romania", 
      "iso2": "RO", 
      "admin_name": "Timiş", 
      "capital": "admin", 
      "population": "319279", 
      "population_proper": "319279"


  },
```

I want to change or add the values on the other JSON file below.

For example if the admin_name from the upper JSON file does not exist in "locations" create it with all the options below "name": Name of the city  , else if it matches with the "name" of the json file below he should Create a new "child" with  {"name" : Name of the CITY, "order": 0},

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "name": "Bucureşti",
      "slug": "",
      "description": "Judet",
      "meta": [
        {"image_id" :  45},
        {"_icon" :  ""}
      ],
      "order": 0,
      "child": [
        {"name": "Bucureşti", "order": 1 },
        {"name" : "Voluntari", "order": 2},
        {"name" : "Fundeni", "order": 3},
        {"name" : "Rosu", "order": 4}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged JavaScript if you're only interested in Python answers?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Do you want to take many input json files and *create the final output json? Or do you want to *update the output json file with new input json files? Also, you should remove javascript tag

Comment: I would recommend, create an object for the first json, and create a dictionary for the second, the key in dict will be admin name.
Then iterate list of input objects and in key in dict - update, if not add new object.
Finally, convert to json.
Should be easy, good luck)